# How can I get count(*) from two tables in one row

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I'm trying to get the total count from each table on one row but getting this error

> "Old style JOIN (ANSI JOINs) syntax is not allowed. Please use
>   standard syntax."

The SQL query I'm using is below. is there an easy way to achieve this

```
SELECT 
(SELECT Count(*) FROM IMPORT_STAGING_DAILYWELCOME_DE) as total_WEL_Stage,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SENDABLE_DE)  AS TOTAL_Pre_Sent
```

Comment: What is the common column between `IMPORT_STAGING_DAILYWELCOME_DE` and `SENDABLE_DE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with a [**CROSS JOIN**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
select 
  t1.total_WEL_Stage
, t2.TOTAL_Pre_Sent
from (
    select count(*) as total_WEL_Stage
    from IMPORT_STAGING_DAILYWELCOME_DE
) as t1
cross join (
    select count(*) as TOTAL_Pre_Sent
    from SENDABLE_DE
) as t2
```